# How to plot continuous colored vector field in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, vectorization

I have 2 matrices `A` and `B`, and by `quiver(A,B)` I can easily plot a vector field. However, does anyone know how to visual vector field in the following way in Matlab?(don't really know the name of this kind of plot)

[image]

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Are you showing magnitude of the vectors? what is the meaning of the colors?

Comment: I guess different colors stand for different velocities.

Comment: You can convert a vector field to HSV color space: magnitude is translated to saturation (the larger the vector - the more vivid the color of the pixel is), and angle is translated to Hue: each direction is encoded in a different color, the mapping is cyclic.

Comment: I suggest you map the components of the vectors to R, B and G (i.e. X direction is red, y is blue and z is green) and then map the magnitude to brightness. So zero is black etc... For example have a look at Fractional Anisotrophy images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a map of magnitude (velocities), then:

```
v = sqrt( A.^2 + B.^2 );
figure; imagesc( v ); colormap jet;colorbar; axis image;
```

Alternatively, if you want results that encode magnitude and direction in HSV color space like this example:
[image]

You can find [this code](https://github.com/bensapp/Stretchable-Models-for-Motion-Parsing/blob/master/thirdparty/mexOpticalFlow/flowToColor.m) useful.