# How to plot orientation and magnitude of a vector field in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I'd like to plot a vector field with its orientation(I already know quiver could help) and jointly with its magnitude as a color plot. I saw another question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540832/how-to-plot-continuous-colored-vector-field-in-matlab) where thery recommend to use HSV but I'd like to see the orientation with quiver jointly with the magnitude as a heat map.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am not sure I get you right, but you can try to plot the data using `quvier`, type `hold on` and then plot the magnitude using e.g. `contourf` to the same figure. (Or actually first magnitude, then quiver, cause the magnitude would hide the previous quiver). Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, that **MagnitudeMat** is a n by m array with vector field magnistudes, **positionsX** and **positionsY** are vectors of length n and m respectively containing positions for **MagnitudeMat** values (vector placements), and **uuu** and **vvv** are n by m arrays with respectively x and y components of vectors:

```
% [1] prepare x and y axis data for drawing                             
[XXX,YYY] = meshgrid(positionsX,positionsY);
% [2] draw the heat map of magnitudes
imagesc(positionsX,positionsY,MagnitudeMat);  
hold on;
% [3] plot streamlines and arrows for vector field
hSlices = streamslice(XXX,YYY,uuu,vvv)
hSlices2 = quiver(XXX,YYY,uuu,vvv);
% [4] some graphical settings
set(hSlices,'LineWidth',1,  'Color' , [.5 .5 .5]);
set(hSlices2,'LineWidth',2, 'Color', [.3 .3 .3]);
colormap('hot');
colorbar('location','eastoutside')
```

I hope this example will help :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try it

Comment: I had another question, How would you compute this MagnitudeMat?, I was thinking about an average of the magnitude of the vectors surrounding each value in positionsX and positionsY. I don't know if it could be done in other way.

Comment: when you have a vector field it means you have a [u,v] at each (x,y) so you can compute magnitude of your vector at each position.